# Posting to my wall instead of others wall FBML Facebook API

Tags: facebook, fbml

for some reason my facebook app is posting to the wall of the user who allowed the app, and not their friends like it's suppose to.

I'm just using a

```
 $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $target_id);
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you aren't using the right method signature.  Here it is as copied from my copy of the file

```
  public function stream_publish(
    $message, $attachment = null, $action_links = null, $target_id = null,
    $uid = null) {
```

So you'd need to call it like so

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish( $message, null, null, $target_id );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're just starting out, you might find the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) and the [new PHP SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) to be easier. For example:

```
<?php

require './facebook.php';

$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR API SECRET',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
$post = $fb->api("$target_id/feed", 'POST', array('message' => $message));
```

The various parameters are documented at the bottom [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post).